# Sorting out mobile numbers on SQL database

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012, excel-2010

All the mobile numbers have gone into the format 447XXXXXXXX, I would like the numbers to be in the format of 07XXXXXXXXXX.

I was going to try the following query:

```
UPDATE stack
SET Telephone= REPLACE(Telephone,'447','07')
```

However, if a number contains 447 this will also be replaced, I was thinking to use wildcards to replace just the first two 4's of every column. How would be the best way to update all 49,000 entries, I have created a backup just in case.

***UPDATE***

It seems the numbers were set in the wrong format so the following query was used to put them in the correct format:

```
ALTER TABLE stack ALTER COLUMN Telephone VARCHAR(15)
```

Now ALL the numbers are showing up in a weird format: 4.47944e+011

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Excel I am using 2010, I used excel to import my data, it was formatted wrong at one point. I corrected the cell values and imported back into SQL server, and now this is my last issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your data type to `varchar` (number data types don't store leading zeros). To do that you need to change it to `bigint` first, to make the conversion work:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN Telephone BIGINT;
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN Telephone VARCHAR(15);
```

After that you can change your data like this

```
UPDATE your_table
SET Telephone = '07' + substring(Telephone, 4,99)
WHERE charindex('447', Telephone) = 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b39ef/1)

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

I think the issue may still be to do with the formats of the numbers too maybe?

Comment: You use `float`as data type of a phone number? Use a `varchar` or a `bigint`, but not a `float`

Comment: It was preset and somewhere down the line was changed, Is it possible for me to change them to varchar or bigint all at once. Over 49k values

Comment: `ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN Telephone VARCHAR(15)`

Comment: Msg 232, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 447944423550.000000.
The statement has been terminated.

No idea what happened there

Comment: I updated my comment. Did not know you had such long phone numbers. I changed `varchar(10)` to `varchar(15)`

Comment: This executed but now created the issue I first had. The numbers are showing as 4.47XXXXXe+011 the format for all the numbers has gone like this now. Before I exported this into excel, corrected the format and put it back in, but that changes the format so I am going in circles!

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You should convert float to bigint and bigint to varchar. Your error message says you tried to convert varchar to bigint. Do it like in the Fiddle demo. It works there

Comment: This has sorted out the issue! Voted as answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change the source (and avoid conversion requirements in future?):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="44",0&MID(A1,3,15),LEFT(A1,15))
```

This results in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work. I gave an example as well... You need to only use the UPDATE statement...

```
DECLARE @Telephone TABLE(Telephone VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Telephone 
SELECT '44712345' UNION ALL
SELECT '123447' UNION ALL
SELECT '447123447' 

SELECT *
FROM @Telephone

UPDATE @Telephone
SET Telephone = STUFF(Telephone, 1, 3, '07')
WHERE (charindex('447', Telephone) = 1)

SELECT *
FROM @Telephone
```

Comment: Although the query seems fine, it does not change anything in my table, which leads to me believe it could be to do with the cell properties?

Comment: And that query would also replace `447` in the middle of phone number.

Comment: @juergend Thanks... I saw that and updated the query... See the updated answer... I have given data example as well...

Answer (score 0):

1) Phone number are stored (usually) using a VARCHAR column.

2) Assuming that the *old* Telephone column was a FLOAT column, if you Telehone column (now a VARCHAR(15) column) has values like `'4.47944e+011'` then you need to convert these values back to FLOAT and then you have to use STR to convert FLOAT values to VARCHAR. For example, following script

```
DECLARE @PhoneFromFloat VARCHAR(15) = '4.47944e+011'
SELECT STR(CONVERT(FLOAT, @PhoneFromFloat), 15, 0)
```

outputs: `447944000000`.

To execute this update you could use this script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  dbo.Stack
SET     Telephone = STR(CONVERT(FLOAT, Telephone), 15, 0)
OUTPUT  deleted.Telephone, inserted.Telephone -- This clause will show affected phone numbers
WHERE   Telephone LIKE '%e%';

ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT
```

Note: you could avoid these problems if you import phone numbers into a `VARCHAR` column directly and not into a `FLOAT` column.

3) Then you could use:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  dbo.Stack
SET Telephone = STUFF(Telephone, 1, 2, '0')
WHERE   Telephone LIKE '447%';

ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT
```

Note: you could do this replace in Excel using, of course, Excel functions.